# Data-binding works first time only, in a detail view

Tags: kendo-mobile

In [this plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/OQV7dVknDYrC3qkWF3XB?p=preview), data-binding of the detail view works on first show, but does not update when navigating to other items.

What is missing ? Thanks!

Html:

```
<body>
<div data-role="view" data-model="aViewModel" id="aView">
  <div data-role="header">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <span data-role="view-title">Master</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" 
    data-bind="source: items, events : { click : onClickItem}" 
    data-template="itemsTemplate">

  <script id="itemsTemplate" type="text/html" >
        <a href="##">#:name#</a>
  </script>

  </ul>
</div>

<div data-role="view" id="aDetailView" 
  data-model="aViewModel.currentItem"
  data-show="aViewModel.onDetailViewShow">
  <div data-role="header">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <span data-role="view-title" data-bind="text:name"></span>
      <a data-align="left" data-role="backbutton">Back</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" >
    <li>Name <span data-bind="text: name"></span></li>
    <li>Value <span data-bind="text: value"></span></li>
  </ul>

</div>


<script src="script.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body );

ViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;

  function Item (name, value)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }

  self.items = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        new Item("AAA",1),
        new Item("BBB",2),
        new Item("CCC",3)
      ]
  }); 

  self.currentItem = null;

  self.onClickItem = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    self.set("currentItem", e.dataItem);
    app.navigate("#aDetailView", "slide");
  }

  self.onDetailViewShow = function(e) {
  }

  self = kendo.observable(this);
  return self;
};

var aViewModel = new ViewModel();
```